# Is it possible to find out the type of an expression between two template parameters?

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm creating a librairy in C++ to handle matrix of any type, and I would like to be able to do basic operations between two matrices of different type.

Let's say I have a matrix A with an int type and a matrix B with a double type.

When we add these two matrices we should obtain a matrix C of the type which result from : int + double (in this case double should be preferred to avoid the loss of data).

I'm using a template with two type : T1 and T2 to handle the different types of my matrices and I've tried using typeid to get the type of the returned matrix. But because typeid doesn't work with T1 and T2 (if i understood correctly) I'm stuck.

```cpp
template<class T1, class T2> Matrix<T1> & operator+(Matrix<T1> Matrix1, Matrix<T2> Matrix2) {
    if(Matrix1.GetCol() != Matrix2.GetCol() || Matrix1.GetRows() != 
Matrix2.GetRows()){
        throw(EXC_DifferentDimensions);
    }

    Matrix<T3> * result = new Matrix<T3>(Matrix1.GetRows(), Matrix1.GetCol());

    for(unsigned int iRow = 0; iRow < Matrix1.GetRows(); iRow++){
        for(unsigned int iCol = 0; iCol < Matrix1.GetCol(); iCol++){
            result->SetElement(Matrix1.GetElement(iRow, iCol) + Matrix2.GetElement(iRow, iCol), iRow, iCol);
        }
    }
    return *result;
}
```

Is it possible to make it work or am i stuck with sticking with a specific type for the returned Matrix ?

Comment: Do note that `Matrix<T3> * result = new Matrix<T3>(Matrix1.GetRows(), Matrix1.GetCol()); ... return *result;` is more than likely going to result in a memory leak unless you call delete on the address of the reference returned by your function.  Instead of returning a reference you should return by value and then change `result` to `Matrix<T3>  result = Matrix<T3>(Matrix1.GetRows(), Matrix1.GetCol());`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask C++ what would be the result of `T1 + T2`:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
Matrix<decltype(std::declval<T1>() + std::declval<T2>()>&
operator+(Matrix<T1> Matrix1, Matrix<T2> Matrix2);
```

[`decltype(e)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/decltype) is the type of the unevaluated expression `e`; [`std::declval<T>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) has type `T` (this function must not appear in a potentially evaluated context).

Comment: I'd make it a type trait matrix_add_t<T1, T2> probably.. but looks great :)

Comment: @xaxxon absolutly ;)